# Proof of whether a specific element is in a commutative, invertible monoid.

Tags: proof-verification, monoid

> M is a commutative monoid with identity element denoted by e.
>
> U(M) is the set of all invertible elements of M.
>
> Let a∈M and b∈M. Prove that if ab∈U(M), then a∈U(M).

I'm not sure if the way I approached this question is legitimate or whether there's a clearer way to show it.

**Method:**

Let ab ∈ U(M).

Hence $(ab)^{-1}$ ∈ U(M).

⇒ $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ ∈ U(M)

⇒ (ab)($b^{-1}a^{-1}$) ∈ U(M)

⇒ $aa^{-1}$ ∈ U(M)

Similarly for ba ∈ M we have:

$(ba)^{-1}$ ∈ U(M)

⇒ $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ ∈ U(M)

⇒ $a^{-1}b^{-1}$(ba) ∈ U(M)

⇒ $a^{-1}$a ∈ U(M).

As *a ∈ M* has a right inverse and left inverse in U(M), we can conclude that *a ∈ U(M)*.

Comment: Writing $a^{-1}$ presupposes $a$ has an inverse.

Comment: Does this mean that the line "(ab)$^{−1}$∈ U(M)." is also incorrect?

Comment: No, you know $ab \in U(M)$, so it has an inverse, and that inverse is denoted $(ab)^{-1}$.

Comment: I see. In that case how would you find the inverse of ab? Or if that's the wrong approach to this question, how would you go about proving the required result?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $ab$ has an inverse $c$. Then $(ab)c = 1$, whence $a(bc) = 1$.
Since $M$ is commutative, we also have $(bc)a = 1$ and thus $bc$ is an inverse of $a$.