# Let $R$ be a ring and let $a \in R$. Let $n \in N$. Show that if $a^n$ has an inverse, a has an inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I can say that $(a^n)^{-1}(a^n)=e$ but I do not know how to use that to show that a has an inverse. Not sure if I just have to manipulate the equation somehow to obtain the result.

Comment: You should say whether or not $R$ is assumed commutative (but the question is surely a dupe either way).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1605664/29335 is close, but there is probably a better dupe.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $a^n b=1$, then $a a^{n-1} b = 1$. Also, $1=b a^n b=b a^{n-1}a$.

Answer (score 2):

We wish to show that $\exists$ $c\in R$ such that $ac=e$.

Let $b$ be the inverse of $a^n$.

Then we have $a^nb=e$.

But we can readily observe that $a(a^{n-1}b)=e$. So $c=a^{n-1}b$ is the inverse of $a$.

Comment: It is not obvious that $a^{n-1}ba  = 1$, one should check the element has inverses at both sides, hence an inverse, see e.g. the spoiler in my answer.

Comment: @guidoar Multiplication does not need to be commutative though, right? So we can verify for one-side only and if the requirement is present then indeed treat it as you so. That said, I do believe your approach is more thorough.

Comment: Multiplication need not be commutative so one should speak of right and left inverses of $x$ to mean $xb = 1$ and $ax = 1$ respectively. When *both* exist then they are equal, since $a = axb = b$ and then we can say $a = b =: x^{-1}$ is the inverse of $x$. But yeah, in the commutative case your remark does the job (also, my comment was rather for the OP, just in case they forget this detail, as an exact same argument exhibits the right inverse).

Comment: @guidoar Ok, thanks for the clarification. Indeed, this is the more "complete" treatment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** if $n = 2$, we have $aau = a^2u = 1 = ua^2 = uaa$ for some $u \in R$. What's the inverse of $a$? Generalize this to any $n$.

> Concretely since $1 = a^{n}(a^{n})^{-1} = aa^{n-1}a^{-n}$ and likewise $1 = (a^n)^{-1}a^n = (a^n)^{-1}a^{n-1}a$ then $a$ has both a left and right inverse, and so it has an inverse (in general, if $ax = xb = 1$ then $a = axb = b$).